# Laravel 5. Dropdown doesn't change database

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a problem. I added dropdown to form, but He only shows the list. When I click on buttun "send" my database doesn't change. `Form::text` change my database, but `Form::select` doesn't make any changes. May, i have a problem in the controller?

**Controller**

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $user = User::with('roles')->findOrFail($id);
    $userRole = Role::pluck('name', 'id');
    return view('pages.edit', compact('user', 'userRole'));
}

public function update($id, Request $request)
{
    $user = User::with('roles')->findOrFail($id);
    $user->update($request->all());
    return redirect('users');
}
```

**View**

```
{!! Form::model($user, ['method' => 'PATCH', 'action'=>['UsersController@update', $user->id]]) !!}
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="form-group col-md-offset-3 col-md-6">
    {!! Form::label('roles','Roles: ') !!}
    {!! Form::select('roles',$userRole, null,['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-md-offset-3 col-md-6">
        {!! Form::submit('Send', ['class'=>'btn btn-success form-control']) !!}
    </div>
</div>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

**Has Role**

```
    public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class);
    }

    public function assignRole($role)
    {
        return $this->roles()->save(
            Role::whereName($role)->firstOrFail()
        );
    }
```

Thx for help.

Comment: I supose `roles` is a relation on your model? You will have to use a separate query to create this relation. Please show your `User` and `Role` model.

Comment: Put `print_r($request->all());exit();` into your `update()` and let me know the output.

Comment: @Jerodev I updated post

Comment: @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd Result:
Array ( [_method] => PATCH [_token] => sbsSGt9lkR12WlG2MRuYKt627JE6Hy7ZX9IAGCjb [name] => bot2 [email] => bot2@bot.com [roles] => 3 )

Comment: what is the column name into users table to hold the role id?

Comment: Add that column name into user model > `protected $fillable`

Comment: @funfelfonfafis: Got it?

Comment: @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd this can be a solution but its pretty bad practice since it allows for malicious setting of the role_id, since he already has a helper that assign a role, that is not necessary

Comment: @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd i use table `role_user` with `user_id` and `role_id`

Comment: @Christophvh: Document say's "While $fillable serves as a "white list" of attributes that should be mass assignable". See [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent)

Comment: @funfelfonfafis: Any package that you are using for ACL?

Comment: @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd yes exactly. And you never want any id's to be mass assignable.

Comment: @Christophvh: Ohh, yes. thanks to draw my attention...+1

Comment: @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd i think, i dont use or i don't know about it :)

Comment: @funfelfonfafisnp, can you please update your question with store method?

Comment: Problem solved, thank you all for help ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Roles is a relationship you need to attach or associate the roles to your user. Depending on the type of relationship.

You will have to attach the role_id to your user model, add this in your controller:

```
$user->roles()->attach($request->roles);
$user->save();
```

As noted in the comments, the keys on your drop-down fields are the id's of the roles.

ps: these are the basics of laravel eloquent, so i would suggets to read the documentation first. https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships

Comment: I tried it before but got the result: _No query results for model [App\Role]._

Comment: That means that whatever role-name you are inserting inside assingRole() doenst exist inside the database. What do you get when you do: 
dd($request->all())  inside your controller .

Comment: `array:5 [▼
  "_method" => "PATCH"
  "_token" => "sbsSGt9lkR12WlG2MRuYKt627JE6Hy7ZX9IAGCjb"
  "name" => "bot2"
  "email" => "bot2@bot.com"
  "roles" => "1"
]`

Comment: That explains it, your roles is giving back the id of the role, but it expects the name. in your method so it won't work. I will update my answer.

Comment: Its working, gj bro ;)
I could not solve it very long. Thank you very much.